# Query set filtering by Primary Key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, datatables

I have a website which firstly designed to show dynamically added or removed models in datatables. Now the data increases and i added serverside processing. The issue is I have a  custom page for each foreign key to show data that belongs to itself now i am stuck with how to filter queryset for the foreign key id and set an api url for server side processing. I hope i was clear. Thanks for your attention

```
class Process(models.Model):
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    entry_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=77)
```

In views i have a view:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = ProcessSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        pk = self.request.parser_context['kwargs']['pk']
        queryset = Process.objects.filter(user__pk=pk)
        return queryset
```

Api page returns in url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user_processes/1/?format=datatables

{"data":{"id":1,"user":{"id":1,"name":"tealy","phone":null,"email":null,"date_created":"2021-10-17T21:15:42.131996+03:00"},"entry_date":"2021-10-17","user":1, "product":null},"recordsFiltered":6354,"recordsTotal":6354,"draw":1}
```

which means i have the count of all the processes that belongs to the user but i could not obtain information of the processes.

URLs:

```
path("user_processes/<int:pk>/", views.user_processes, name="user_processes")
router.register(r'user_processes', views.UserViewSet, basename='UserProcess')
```

Comment: Show some models and a bit of view code. What have you tried?

Comment: Hey i added the models and viewset

Comment: Hey @webtweakers I added all the code so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

views.py:

```
 class UserView(generics.ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = ProcessSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        pk = self.request.parser_context['kwargs']['id']
        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        queryset = Process.objects.filter(user=user)
        return queryset
```

urls.py (Project):

```
path('api/users/<int:id>/', views.UserView.as_view(), name='users'),
```

urls.py (App):

```
path("users/<int:pk>/", views.users, name="users"),
```

views.py:

```
def users(request, pk):
    return render(request, 'tealyapp/temp.html', {'pk': pk})
```